# selenium grid: can't connect to hub and node

Tags: selenium-grid

I encounter some problems to set up a selenium grid.  Yet I tried to refer to the instructions of several tutorials.

I placed the selenium server in a particular folder. I open 2 terminals from this folder.
In one I enter the following command

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.1.1.jar -role hub
```

I get the following answer:

[image]

In the second one:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444
```

I get the following answer:

[image]

my configuration:

- Lenovo terra
- Linux Ubuntu 20.04
- usual chrome browser
- selenium server 4.1.1

I saw the same thing on several tutorials. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem, the correct command is:

```
java -jar selenium-server-<your version>.jar standalone
```

Comment: how did you connect a node on another device to standalone server?